# Facebook Conversions API with Google Cloud instead of AWS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I'm trying to follow [this set of instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/guides/gateway/setup#step-2:%7E:text=Troubleshooting-,Conversions%20API%20Gateway%3A%20Setup%20Guide,-Use%20the%20following) for setting up Conversions API. However, it requires AWS Account which we don't have. What we currently do have is Google Cloud Platform.

Is Conversions API able to be set up with Google Cloud?

I'm completely new to setting up something like this and I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their documentation, Facebook Conversions API is compatible with Google Cloud Platform through Google Tag Manager. Here is the link for your reference. [1]

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/guides/gtm-server-side#configure-your-gtm-portal

Comment: You are correct that Google Tag Manager does have support for CAPI. It seems like the original poster might be referring to CAPI Gateway. They are two different solutions for a similar use case. I just wanted to point out that CAPI Gateway is only supported on AWS at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

they mentioned that their gateway approach only use support aws for now. here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/guides/gateway

Comment: I got it to work with GCP so that must be outdated